# representing hierarchical relationship

Tags: java

Can you suggest me "How can I represent the  hierarchical relationship through  java class?"
you are welcomed to suggest other techniques.

For  instance,   User specifies  that

```
       "Room" belongs-to "Floor" and  "Floor" belongs-to "Center"
```

I want to represent this relationship as Java class, and  later want to retrieve this relationship.

-Pankesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is standard [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)

'Belongs-to' and 'contains' are rather similar here. So for example:

```
public class Center
{
   private List<Floor> floors;
   ...
   public List<Floor> getFloors()
   {

      return this.floors;
   }
}

public class Floor
{
   private List<Room> rooms
   ...
}

public class Room
{
   private String roomNumber;
   ...
}
```